# Addition of increment result, depends on user Input

Tags: c#

The user where input number not equal to 0. Example If the user where try to input 5 number at the `TextBox` then it should automatically increment and  display in `Label1` and the result of addition will display in `Label2` and the answer of 5 decrement will be exactly 15. Any ideas?

This is my code anyway:

```
private int result;
private int var1;

var1 = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text);
do{ 

 Label1.Text += var1.ToString();
 var1++;

 } while(var1!=0)
```

Comment: Yes, I have ideas.

Comment: My idea is that you should make an attempt

Comment: Yep, many ideas, if you initiate means we will help you to complete, what is the difficulty that you are facing?

Comment: Can you give me an example Sir? on while loop?

Comment: your code isn't valid,  you need to decide if you are doing C# or vb..... and try using a debugger to help get a better understanding of what's going on.  Visual Studio debugging is one of the best in the industry.

Comment: It is really unclear what are you trying to achieve

Comment: Because `var1` is increasing by 1 each time, the loop is not going to end until `var1` overflows, because you tell it to continue while `var1` is not zero. You'll easily see what happens in the debugger. DEBUG -> Start debugging